# Getting information about all types of external storage in Android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Most devices have only one internal storage and one external storage (which is usually SD card, and is removeable).

The API has methods that you can ask it if the external storage is [removable or not](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#isExternalStorageRemovable%28%29), and [get its path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29). As of API 11, I think it's also possible to check if the external storage is actually a part of the device (via [isExternalStorageEmulated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)).

However, some devices (like Galaxy S/S2/S3) have more than one external storage, each is either removable or not, and each has its own path. For such devices, for some reason "[isExternalStorageEmulated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#isExternalStorageEmulated%28%29)" returns true; I'm not even sure what it means, since it has both types of external storage.

How do I get information about all of the external storage, such as the following (the first two are most important for me):

- path
- isRemoveable
- type of storage (for example: sdcard, inner device, HDD...)
- connection type (usb, card reader, mounted file...). I don't think that's possible since there is already an API for [USB](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html)